Ceiling fan dual color lighting switching
Some ceiling fans now have two different sets of LEDs, of different color temperatures, which are selected by switching the power on/off. I would like to know how this switching circuit works, it has some kind of "memory", and I don´t know if it is mechanically switched... Any ideas?

there are some light bulbs that have that functionality ... I've seen one that has three modes

hint: it takes time for power supply output voltages to die when power is turned off

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
